# Динамический поиск и вывод в приложении Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

Приветствую! 
У меня есть таблица в базе данных, данного вида (Пример): `ID`, `NAME`, `ABOUT`, `CATEGORY`.

Заполняем строки:

```
[id=1, name=var1, about=info,  category=1,2,3]
[id=2, name=var2, about=info2, category=1,3  ]
[id=3, name=var3, about=info3, category=1,2  ]
[id=4, name=var4, about=info4, category=1,3  ]
```

Каким образом можно сделать отбор по категориям (например пользователь выбирает через `ListView` критерий 1 и 3, т.е в списке должно вывести данные `id` равный 2 и 4)? В какую сторону стоит копать?

Comment: Не понял в чем проблема. Нужен SQL запрос?

Comment: @АлександрМартынцев, как запрос сделать я знаю, но по одному (критерию и т.д). Тут у меня ступор как по нескольким критериям пройтись, которые в 1 ячейке грубо говоря располагаются, и вывести строго именно те, где идет совпаддение. Т.е в ID1 у меня тоже есть 1 и 3, но есть и 2, поэтому эта строка не должна попадать в выводимый список.

Comment: В таком случае в `category` нужно хранить отсортированные (пор возрастанию или убыванию) значения, а в запросе делать `WHERE category = '1,3'`. Подставляемые значения в строке `1,3` также должны быть отсортированы в том же порядке.

Comment: @Regent, в примере цифры, в деле будут слова, их по возрастанию и убыванию не отсортируешь, лишь по алфавиту. Либо создавать несколько таблиц в которой будут ИД и категории, а потом эти значения выводить в данной?

Comment: Сортировка по алфавиту ничуть не хуже будет работать. Главное чтобы одинаково сортировались при добавлении и при запросе. Если в словах для категорий могут быть запятые, то безусловно лучше создать отдельную таблицу для категорий.

Comment: А вообще, хранение нескольких значений через сепаратор (как у вас в `category`) в поле допустимо только если это поле не используется в `WHERE` или если совпадение всегда должно быть полным (как вам нужно в данном случае). Это я к чему веду: если вдруг вам понадобится выдавать и `id=1` (так как там тоже есть `1` и `3`), то нужно будет делать отдельную таблицу для связи вашей таблицы с таблицей категорий.

Comment: @Regent, вот я и задумываюсь о связанной таблице критериев, ибо их до 10-15 может быть в каждой строке. Т.е. Сортировка нужна обязательно (Пример: '1,2,3', '2,7,11;', '4,8,10') и т.д?

Comment: В большинстве случаев правильным будет создание таблицы `ProductCategories` (предположим, что таблица в вопросе называется `Products`, в которой и будут храниться связки `product_id` с `category_id`. Это позволяет использовать SQL без кучи костылей. Однако, повторюсь, в случае обязательного полного совпадения (только `1,3` и никаких `1,2,3`) допустимо и даже проще в использовании создание строки с несколькими значениями (предпочтительно числовыми) через сепаратор.

Comment: @Regent, выходит, если я забиваю критерии, будь то цифры или слова через разделитель, при выборе пользователем например 1 и 3, ему выдаст список только с содержанием критерия 1 и 3, а иды с 1,2,3 и т.д пройдут мимо?

Comment: Да. Но вы же сами этого хотели, судя по вашему первого комментарию. А мои комментарии про создание доп. таблицы направлены на случай, если вдруг вы передумаете.

Comment: @Regent, нет нет, все верно, мне необходимо полное совпадение, и никаких дополнительных критериев входить не должно. Если выбрано пользователем 1 и 3, то и выдать ему должно "продукты" содержащие только эти 2 критерия.

Comment: Что-то много комментариев получилось. Как бы не получить втык от модераторов (переходить в чат не хочу). Так что сделаю подведение итогов. В любом случае стоит создать таблицу категорий, а для связки использовать их `id` вместо названий. Если совпадение будет всегда только полным, то вполне можно оставить `id` категорий через запятую в поле. В этом случае условие выборки сильно упрощается, однако нужно будет сортировать `id` категорий при вставки и при выборке. В случае хранения связки в виде доп. таблицы будет проблемно сделать "эти и только эти категории", но зато других сложностей не будет.